# Synaptic 'Complete Removal' messed my system

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

I'm having a bad time trying to flash a android ROM in my phone. It almost take me to the need of using windows again for runing 'Odin'. After searching I found 'Heimdall', but has some problems installing it the first time.

When trying again I first came to Synaptic to remove the first heimdall packages and make another clean install. So I checked 'Complete Removal' to one heimdall package, and it told me that my action would act in other various packages, but in this moment I believed that it was ok. Well, after restarting the system my terminal turned lo-profile, my status bar, clock, program dock and everything just vanished.

How to clean up this mess I've just made to my system? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look to `/var/log/apt/history.log` and see what has been removed.

Then just re-install what is missing.

I would suggest to start with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

This may be enough.

Comment: What a fast and good answer. The history.log file showed me SO MUCH things and I almost lost my faith at this point, but the apt reinstall gave me an error, told me to do a " -f" procedure, I did, and after that tryed again and it reinstalled a lot of things, various names I've recognise by the .log file. Now I'm here on a working good ubuntu again in just 5 minutes after asking. I could give your answer a star if it was possible. Thank you so much.